# Multiple where conditions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm implementing a user search feature in my Rails app. However, I don't want admins to appear in the search results.

I'm trying this:

```
User.where(:admin => [nil, false], ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

But I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
```

So how do I properly list `where` clauses inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this

```
User.where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"]).where(:admin => [nil, false])
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked this out in the Rails console, and it seems to just convert it to `WHERE a AND b` in SQL. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Why does the first `.where` clause go inside an array? i.e. inside `[` and `]`